# Mongodb cluster Kubernetes Stateful set is not deleting

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset, kubernetes-operator, mongodb-cluster

I have created Mongodb stateful set using [mongodb kubernetes operator](https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator).

Now I want to delete that stateful set from kubernetes dashboard, but it is getting recreated again and again.

How do we delete stateful set permanently so that it doesn't get created again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do we delete stateful set permanently so that it doesn't get
> created again.

List and check the name of statefulset

```
kubectl get statefulsets -n <namespace name>
```

Command to delete the stateful set permanently

```
kubectl delete statefulset <Mongo statefulset name> -n <namespace name>
```

**Update**

Try deleting the CRD also

```
kubectl get crd
```

delete CRD for mongo

```
kubectl delete crd <CRD name>
```

Comment: It is getting created again even after this command :(

Comment: check the CRD and delete CRD for Mongo also. `Kubectl get crd` also delete the deployment if any exist `kubectl get deployment` check the RS

Comment: Ohk. That was it. needed to delete CRD as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please update your answer. As that is actual answer. Deleting CRD.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to delete a pod or the Stateful set itself?

Try to run:

```
kubectl scale sts <Stateful Set name> --replicas=0 -n <your namespace>
```

Comment: I am trying to set scale 0 from dashboard. but it creates 2 replicas. if I give 1 then it works and creates 1 replica.

Answer (score 0):

For deleting pod forcefully use this.

```
kubectl delete pod <Pod_Name> -n <namespace_name>  --grace-period=0  --force
```

OR

```
kubectl delete pod <Pod_Name> -n <namespace_name>  --wait=false
```

For reference please follow below link. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/force-delete-stateful-set-pod/